# How to graph $y=4x^2-4x^4$

Tags: graphing-functions

In physics when learning simple harmonic motion they gave us the x coordinates dependence on time and similarly for the y coordinates

I got the resulting equation of path taken as $y=4x^2-4x^4$ which I have no idea how to graph

Is this a significant graph like the ellipse and hyperbola whose equation would be helpful to memorize .

Although to solve the question this graph is not required ,my query is just that if given this graph how would I plot it

Comment: This is a rather basic quartic function in $x$.  Do you know how to graph polynomial functions?

Comment: For interest's sake, this function in $x$ can be rearranged as $y=1-(1-2x^2)^2$.

Comment: You could just study it as a function: see where it equals zero, take the derivatives and study their signs finding local maxima/minima an then study it's behaviour towards infinity. This should give you all the informations about the graph.

Comment: @Rhino Arg why didn't I think of that ,thanks alot .Could you copy paste that into an answer?

Comment: So, you are online and asking how to graph a function given in the form $y=f(x)$ in the time of Desmos, WolframAlpha etc.???

Comment: @trancelocation I get this comment alot when I ask graphical questions here ,Desmos won't help in an exam where I can't use Desmos lol.This was asked in an exam where calculators of any sort are not allowed .

Comment: @Glowingbluejuicebox Then, you should clearly indicate this in your question. And if you get comments like mine "a lot", you should finally start studying how to graph functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just study it as a function: see where it equals zero, take the derivatives and study their signs finding local maxima/minima an then study it's behaviour towards infinity. This should give you all the informations about the graph.